# BinaryStdOut.write doesnt print the Binary Output

Tags: java, binary, huffman-code

some is the root of the Huffman Trie . 
I am trying to print the Binary traversing through the Trie in PreOrder , But the binary output is not getting displayed . Could someone help

```
Huffman.writeTrie(some);


  protected static void writeTrie(Node x) {

        if (x.isLeaf()) {
            BinaryStdOut.write(true);
            BinaryStdOut.write(x.ch, 8);

            return;
        }
        BinaryStdOut.write(false);

        writeTrie(x.left);
        writeTrie(x.right);

    }
```

Comment: Well, since we don't know what `BinaryStdOut` is it'll be a little hard to help.  Is it a class or an object reference? Standard Java naming conventions indicate it's a class and `write` is a static method... but did you follow Java naming conventions?

Comment: I am using the below library                            http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/BinaryStdOut.java.html              The flush() seems to work, But the output is weird.

Example         
BinaryStdOut.write('p', 8);
BinaryStdOut.flush();

Output:
çzºYVûK€

Answer (score 0):

Just googled to see what BinaryStdOut is and found this from Algorithms references at Princeton: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/BinaryStdOut.java.html

And it says in the comments:

> The client must flush() the output stream when finished
>   writing bits.

And I don't see flush in your code, so maybe that's missing? Sounds like flush is calling BufferedOutputStream.flush() and that should do it for you if it was missing. Difficult to answer without seeing the full code.

Comment: Thanks . The flush() seems to work, But the output is weird.

Example         
BinaryStdOut.write('p', 8);
BinaryStdOut.flush();

Output:
çzºYVûK€

Comment: Depends on where you are running it and what data you are writing to the output. Please accept that answer if it helped you get the output in the first place.